# Cracking WEP with Aircrack and Kismet

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, security, wep

Just a minor question, but I notice with aircrack when it lists networks, it does not list the encryption type of each network.

Which seems fair enough, as you can use Kismet, however on my machine when I end kismet and the server, the monitor interface is not removed and I cannot remove it manually, which screws with aircrack.

SO, is kismet needed to view encryption types of networks, and if so how do you use it peacefully in unison with aircrack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Grimwepa: http://code.google.com/p/grimwepa/

run it with -v which will show you which commands its using in the background. it works quite well.

Comment: Not interested in using a third party tool to do something I should be able to do myself, but thanks

Comment: yes but if your running into trouble and you want to figure out how it works, you can reverse engineer how GrimWepa does it. if you use '-v' it will tell you every kismet/aircrack/etc command it executes

Comment: Ahh I see, cheers!